problems with using Tutor LMS in multilingual websites
Hi I am currently building a free multilingual educational website on WordPress and using the lms tutor plugin to manage lessons and students. I am using the polylang plugin to translate the pages of the site, the issue I am facing is that I can translate all the pages of the site but the lms tutor pages are not translated as they remain in the default language. Can you suggest a method or solution to this issue.
